# Unit testing NgRx effect (invoking other effect) to ensure service method called twice

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ngrx

I am using ngrx 8.3.0 and want to test my effects class. Part of it goes like this:

```
    @Effect()
    onSubmit$ = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType<RequestSubmission>(SubmissionActionType.REQUEST_SUBMISSION),
        switchMap(request => {
            return this.service
                .submit(request.content.slice((request.iteration - 1) * 2,request.iteration * 2))
                .pipe(map(s => SubmissionAction.submissionAccepted(request.content, s, request.iteration)),
                    catchError(error => of(SubmissionAction.submissionFailed(error.status)))
                );
        })
    );

    @Effect()
    submissionAccepted$ = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType<SubmissionAccepted>(SubmissionActionType.SUBMISSION_ACCEPTED),
        map(request =>
            request.iteration * 2 < request.content.length
                ? SubmissionAction.requestSubmission(request.content, request.iteration + 1)
                : SubmissionAction.submissionCompleted()
        )
    );
```

As you can see the second effect listens for an action that is called in the first effect. Also (if a condition is met) the second effect calls the action that the first effects listens to. This way we loop through the array `content` and call the service function `submit` in batches of 2 elements each time until the array reaches its end.

I now want to test that with a content of length 3, the `submit` function of my service gets called two times. So far I have the following:

```
    it('should call submit method twice', async () => {
        const countSpy = spyOn(service, 'submit').and.callThrough();

        actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
        const content = ['a80b04a8','155b5a51','a19d0a7a'];
        actions$.next(SubmissionAction.requestSubmission(content, 1));

        await effects.onSubmitReference$.subscribe();
    
        expect(countSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    
    });
```

Unfortunately, the spy detects that the function was called once only.

I also though of subscribing to the second effect independently before expecting the function to have been called twice

```
actions$.next(SubmissionAction.submissionAccepted(content,{result: []}, 1));
await effects.submissionAccepted$.subscribe();
```

But I get the same result. Does anyone know if the subscription of the first effect in the test should invoke the second effect automatically or not?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It look like the second effect simply returns actions, but **does not** dispatch any, so this might be the problem. If it still doesn't work, it would be helpful to create a StackBlitz demo. [Here's](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnvayypprgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth-guard.service.spec.ts) a boilerplate project you could start with.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. The implementation works fine, I have tested it manually. I cannot get the test to pass since I am not sure if by calling the first action and subscribing to the first effect all the process (new effect invoked) is completed automatically like in real life code.

Comment: I think that without dispatching the actions from the second effect inside the test case, it won't work.

Comment: If I dispatch them separately it kind of beats the whole purpose of the test, but thanks again for your input

Comment: Couldn't you dispatch them from the effect itself?

Comment: I was trying to test the existing implementation, apparently maybe I have to refactor the implementation itself.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to test the code with help from my colleagues. In the test I no longer expect the service function to have been called twice, but instead follow the complete flow of effects.

```
it(`should process effects loop correctly`, (done: DoneCallback) => {
    actions$ = new Subject<SubmissionAction>();
    const content = ['a80b04a8','155b5a51','a19d0a7a'];
    let iteration = 1;
    jest.spyOn(service, 'submitReference').mockImplementation(() => {
        const status = 'SUBMITTED';
        const submissionNumbers = content.slice((iteration - 1) * 2, iteration * 2)
        return of(<Submissions>{ submissionNumbers });
    });
    effects.onSubmit$.subscribe(action => {
        expect(action.type).toEqual(SubmissionActionType.SUBMISSION_ACCEPTED);
        actions$.next(action);          
    });
    effects.submissioneAccepted$.subscribe(action => {
        iteration++;
        if (iteration < 3) {
            expect(action.type).toEqual(SubmissionActionType.REQUEST_SUBMISSION);
            expect((action as RequestSubmission).iteration).toEqual(2);
            actions$.next(action);  
        } else {
            expect(action.type).toEqual(SubmissionActionType.SUBMISSION_COMPLETED);
            actions$.complete();            
            done();
        }
    });
    actions$.next(SubmissionAction.requestSubmission(content, iteration));
});
```

To be more clear, we subscribe to both effects (onSubmit and submissioneAccepted) and expect the appropriate action to be invoked based on the iteration of the loop. When loop is complete, so is the subscription and test. Finally we dispatch the first action to trigger the whole process